# Why some buttons of my GridLayout have distance and they aren't showing on the activity

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have a `GridLayout` with buttons and now I have a big empty space between columns 1 and 2 and 3 and 4. The buttons that are the elements of columns (organized by column and row) have a margin of 1 dp. I don't know why I have that space between the two groups of columns.

The `GridLayout`'s design

[image]

The `GridLayout`'s code

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvcifra"
    app:orientation="vertical"
    app:rowCount="5"
    app:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="367dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp">
```

and inside the layout, I have a button like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:text="@string/_1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="48sp" />
```

Comment: The current description is useless. Please add screenshots for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimise your layout code like below which will result

[image: Android Studio Design]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="367dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="73dp"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:orientation="vertical"
    app:rowCount="5">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        app:layout_column="3"
        app:layout_row="2" />
</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I hope it will help you in design rest of the layout.
Happy Coding.